# Assigning SOQL results to a set

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id, set

I am trying to get Id list like this:

```
Set<Id> idSet;
idSet = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
```

But getting this:

```
Illegal assignment from List<Account> to Set<Id>
```

I need to do this to add id:

```
Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
idSet.add( accountList[0].Id);
```

But in the above solution, I need to create `accountList` object just to populate `idSet`.

Is there any other way to populate set of ids using `SOQL` query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instead get the results into `Map` and get the keyset from `Map` to get `Set<Id>`

`Map` has a constructor which takes `List<sObject>` and creates a instance of `Map` with `ID` as `Key` and `sObject` as `value`.

Excerpt from Salesforce [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) documentation.

> `Map<ID,sObject>(recordList)`
>
> Creates a new instance of the Map class and populates it with the
>   passed-in list of sObject records. The keys are populated with the
>   sObject IDs and the values are the sObjects.

So, you can use the above constructor of `Map` and can get a set out of it using `Map's` `keyset()` method.

```
Set<Id> idSet = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]).keyset();
```

You can also go through Salesforce documentation of [Map of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm) and refer Auto-Populating Map entries from a SOQL query.

Comment: +1, good explain. removed my answer

Comment: @salesforce-sas Thanks for correcting the syntax